# Does the FAA Publish the Latitude/Longitude of Parking Locations?

Tags: faa, datasets

In Jeppesen charts, it's known that they provide the latitude/longitude of gate locations at airports. I was wondering if the FAA had a source for the same information, like their international counterparties.

Would anyone know if the FAA keeps that data somewhere? Is Jeppesen extracting the parking locations themselves and putting those in their Navdata and Charts products?

Comment: Stand location is collected as `AircraftGateStand` for airport certification, see [AC 150/5300](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150-5300-18C.pdf#page=141). It should be possible to get this information, after discussing with FAA.